# Multisite files folders

Tags: 7, multi-sites

In a first try to setup a multi-site configuration, I run into the following problem : anything done with a site (pictures, styles...) is added to `sites/default/files/` directory, and an image added to a content points to `sites/default/files/styles/some_style/.../image.jpg`.

**Is it the expected behaviour ?** I thought any file would stay in sites/site1/files...

This is my sites/sites.php  :

```
$sites = array(
  '8083.arbre.dd' => 'arbre.dd', //local devdesktop site
  '8083.site2.dd' => 'site2.dd', //future one
);
```

I have folders `sites/all, sites/default, sites/arbre.dd, sites/site2.dd`.
I added a files directory and a `settings.php` file to the future site folder.
I notice that the arbre.dd folder added by Devdesktop at initial setting, has a shortcut icon ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verify your configuration at `admin/config/media/file-system` on the multisites. "Public file system path" may be configured to `sites/default/files`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, to @Cilefen answer, I'll share here my modest experience : in order to get a **multi-site configuration** :

- I added a first site with the desired profile, which I won't touch nor publish. Just **default profile**, always up to date after performing security updates of the multi-site configuration
- I added then another site with the same sql dump, which is the first real *client* site
- Whenever I wish to add a new site, I'll just have to *dump default profile DB* as a start point, in a new sites folder, and setup "Public file system path" as `sites/newSite/files`

Files, themes or whatever specific to each site is now correctly saved in its directory.

Please comment that answer if I could do a better way